# Deleting all characters in a string that do not belong to a small set of elements

Tags: string-manipulation

Say I have a string {100  aa bbc%j%b%wa ajjcj11j0%2wj fc} with a lot of undesired characters or spaces in it, for example: {" ", "%", "w", "j"}.  I'd like to strip the string of these characters, with the provided example giving us the output string:

```
testString = "100 aa bbc%j%b%wa ajjcj11j0%2wj fc";
StringReplace[testString, {" ", "%", "w", "j"} -> ""]

out: "100aabbcbaac1102fc";
```

Now, say we don't have a convenient list of undesired characters / spaces / paragraph indicators / etc.  Is there a way to select for certain characters instead of specifying that certain characters should be deleted (as in the example)?

Comment: @b.gatessucks Ah, you have to double click to select the full alphanumeric string, and I wasn't paying enough attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
testString = "100 aa bbc%j%b%wa ajjcj11j0%2wj fc";
StringJoin@StringCases[testString, {"a", "j", "c", " "}]

(* aa cja ajjcjjj c *)
```

The second argument for `StringCases` can use character ranges, etc.

As to "bulk" but specific upcase/downcase, something like:

```
StringReplace[%, (# -> ToUpperCase[#]) & /@ {"c", "j"}]

(*  aa CJa aJJCJJJ C *)
```

Comment: This is terrific, thank you.

Comment: Also works with `StringSplit`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks: Good idea- you should post as an answer, I think the more examples of different ways, the better.

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `RegularExpression`

```
StringReplace[testString, RegularExpression["[^ajc ]"] :> ""]
```

Gives:

```
 aa cja ajjcjjj c
```